# Peewee, how to avoid n+1 queries with many-to-many-to-many relation

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have a model with a many-to-many-to-many relation (2 intermediates tables for 3 entity involved)

It looks like that :

Project -> (project_tag) -> Tag -> (intent_tag) -> Intent

I want to retrieve X Intents, and for each Intent, all Tags and all Projects.

With a `prefetch()` I can do that with 2 queries (instead of hundred that could be done automatically), for a simple `many-to-many` relation, but I don't find how to do that with one more `-to-many` relation...

I tried so many things, one for example :

```py
    intent_query = Intent.select().paginate(1, 4)
    intent_tag_query = IntentTag.select(IntentTag, Tag, Intent, ProjectTag, Project) \
        .join(Intent) \
        .switch(IntentTag) \
        .join(Tag) \
        .join(ProjectTag).join(Project) \
        .where(IntentTag.intent.in_(intent_query))

    combo_query = prefetch(intent_query, intent_tag_query)
    result = []
    for res in combo_query:
        intent_dict = model_to_dict(res)
        intent_dict['intent_tags'] = []
        for intent_tags in res.intent_tags:
            intent_tags_dict = model_to_dict(intent_tags)
            intent_tags_dict['project_tags'] = []
            for project_tags in intent_tags.tag.project_tags:
                intent_tags_dict['project_tags'].append(model_to_dict(project_tags))
            intent_dict['intent_tags'].append(intent_tags_dict)
        result.append(intent_dict)
```

With the prefetch, I got 2 queries ; it's not perfect, one query contains the other as subquery, so it's executed 2 times, but it doesn't cost too much so I can accept that...

But with the "project_tags" loop, each turn runs 2 more queries to get data from `project_tag` and `project`, but these data are already available in the first `intent_tag_query` with `join()`'s :/

I hope my question is clear, I can provide more data if it can be useful, I haven't paste models directly because I thought it could ruine readbaility of this post, but I can if you want :)

Thanks !